# Airplane pilot transported back in time to a land ruled by a king also transported back in time

Tags: story-identification, time-travel, novel

I read a book between 1990 and 1992. The only thing I can remember about the book is the cover had a female riding on a dragon and was shooting an arrow into either a F-14 Tomcat or a F-16.

From what I can remember of the storyline the king of the land is a man that was transported from the modern world and uses technology to rule his subjects. Somehow this pilot gets sucked into the same world and his jet is disabled by an arrow to the wing and is forced to crash land. The dragon rider recruits him to go after the king.

Comment: *arrow to the knee

Answer (score 14):

This sounds like a slightly garbled recollection of [*The Wizardry Cursed*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?3717) by [Rick Cook](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rick_Cook), published in 1991.

This is not time travel, but an alternate universe where magic exists and our technology works not at all differently. Several people from our world have been transported to this alternate world, including the hero of the series, the main villain of that book (the king of your recollection), and the pilot. The hero mixes ideas from magic and technology for good. The villain mixes ideas from magic and technology for evil. The pilot and the dragon rider both fight on the good side, and they fall in love.

[image: cover image]

Comment: Giles thank you very much. This was exactly the book I was looking for.